# Teamcity build chain templating

Tags: teamcity

We have set of different web application projects, which is delivered by Teamcity to different environments. At this moment, we are doing all-in-one builds: compile, package and deploy at once; all based on a templates.

Now I am investigating a way to separate concenrs: one build tests and produces package, another - delivers. Naturally, both builds are having own templates. Is there a way to template this build chain - so, when I choose some meta-template - both builds will be created with present Artifact dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly not. What we've had to do is clone the build chains. We've put in place a mechanism which makes sure the set-ups of the different chains do not diverge.

Another option, admittedly ugly, is to set up a single build chain and let each of your projects pretend that it's a separate VCS branch. In this case there's a single set-up (for the single build chain) and to view the history of a given project you filter by that project "branch". Needless to say, that's not how branches should be used and you may run into some issue down the line.

Comment: Thank you. I supposed so, but hoped that maybe I missed something